# I get a 405 error when uploading a JPEG image from an iOs app to a Rester server. (swift/python)

Tags: swift, xcode, http, image-upload

I'm creating an iOs application in Xcode as part of a programming minor, I want to upload images to a Rester server and save them in a folder.

I have the image picker and picture controller set up in Xcode and did my best to understand the documentation of Rester, yet I still can't seem to get it right. I tried converting the image to a string, but that only complicated things, and I should be able to simply upload the image itself.

Here is the code for the app:

```swift
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            imageView.image = pickedImage
        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    func uploadImage() {
        let imageFile = imageView.image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)
        if imageFile == nil { return }
        PictureController.shared.uploadImage(forPicture: imageFile!) {_ in
            print(self.picture)
        }
    }


    func uploadImage(forPicture picture: Data, completion: @escaping (Picture?) -> Void) {
        var request = URLRequest(url: uploadUrl)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        // Picture
        request.httpBody = picture

        // Upload Picture
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data,
            response, error) in
            let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
            if let data = data,
                let picture = try?
                    jsonDecoder.decode(Picture.self, from: data) {
                completion(picture)
            } else {
                completion(nil)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

And here is the code on the server:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
from flask import Flask, request, g, flash, redirect, url_for, send_from_directory
from flask_restful import abort, Api, Resource
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from database import *

UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'pictures'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'The Key'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 64 * 1024 * 1024
api = Api(app)

ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])



class Picture(Resource):
    def upload_file(self):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            f = request.files
            f.save('uploads/uploaded_file')
            return jsonify({'success': True})

api.add_resource(Picture, '/picture_upload')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I expected the image to be neatly placed into the folder, but instead I get a 405 message telling me I'm doing something that is not allowed.

This is my first time posting, any help would be greatly appreciated, being in regards to the problem but also with the formulation of my question.